Normalized Difference Turbidity Index (NDTI) wrong
I'm trying to retrieve a turbidity indicator from a Landsat 8 using NDTI :
NDTI=(Red-Green)/(Red+Green).
The problem is the result is not consistent with the reality.
Here is a RGB visualization where we can clearly see the turbidity on close to the coast (brown clouds) :

And this is the red band :

And the green band :

They are both on the same scale which is reflectance from 0 to 0.1.
The resulting NDTI :

While we can clearly see the turbidity pattern on Band 3 & Band 4 the problem is that the reflectances on Band 3 are greater than on Band 4 even when the water is turbid. The NDTI is not working at all then and showing an increase in turbidity in the middle of the lake and low turbidity level in the area of high turbidity.
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this ?
Note that the RGB visualisation is from one day before, explaining the pattern difference in the turbidity.

NDTI is a single number so obviously some color ramp is used in the NDTI image. Could you show that? What is the datatype of the NDTI output raster, does it support negative numbers?

NDTI is calculated from band reflectance (so ranging from 0 to 0.1). Reflectance can, by physical constraint, not be negative. The negative reflectance are masked in those images

If red=0.1 and green=0.2, then (red-green=-0.1) and NDTI is -0.1/0.3=-0.333.

Yes, NDTI is a normalized index ranging from -1 to 1. The question here is more related with the fact that low reflectance in the red band are obtained while it must be greater

What makes you believe that red reflectance must be greater?

Because my turbidity indicator does not reflect at all the patterns of turbidity in particular in the middle of the lake

I am having the same problem. Turbidity (red*green/blue) shows an increase over time whereas NDTI is trending downwards over time. I am using Landsat 7, 8 and 9.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
